# Finish iterating through 2 functions and then go to next function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, ecmascript-6, async-await

I have two functions that call each other till the `forEach` loop is done. I want to call a 3rd function after the 2 functions completely finish executing their code.

My Code

```
const mainFunc = (fn) => {
  return async (query_name, ...args) => {
    const result = await axios_Func(query_name);
    try {
      return fn(result, ...args);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
};

const createOne = mainFunc((result) => {
  let table_id = result.data.internal_id;
  axios_Func({ graphQL query }).then((response) => {
     createTwo({ query: graphQL_query, table_id).then((res) => res);
  });
});

createTwo = mainFunc(async (result, table_id) => {
  let dev = await getAllTables({ query: tables(123) });
  let prod = await getAllTables({ query: tables(321) });
  let prod_id = new Set();
  result.data.data.table.table_fields.forEach((d) => {
    if (d. connector != null && !(d.name in dev))
      prod_id.add(prod[d.name]["id"]);
  });
  prod_id = [...prod_id];
  console.log(prod_id);
  await Promise.all(
     prod_id.map((x) => createOne({ query: graphQL_query(x) }).then((res) => res))
   );
});

const createThree = mainFunc(async (result, table_id) => {
    //do something
});
```

My code currently returns:

```
[123, 456]
[]
[567, 897]
[345, 987]
[]
```

Is there a way to merge these values into 1 array to look like `[123, 456, 567, 897, 345, 987]` outside of `createTwo` and then iterate over these after `createOne and createTwo` finish executing to call the `createThree` function?

Comment: FYI, `.then((res) => res)` is pointless.  Remove it.

Comment: `createOne()` needs to return the `axios_Func()` promise and then you also need to return the nested `createTwo()` promise.  As it stands now, the caller of `createOne` has NO idea when it's done.  And, the `await Promise.all()` in `createTwo()` doesn't work properly because `createOne()` isn't returning a promise that is connected to when it's done.

Comment: Why not just make `createOne()` `async` and use `await` in it for both operations instead of `.then()`.  That will simplify things.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks for `.then((res) => res)` tip. I am a noob. with `promises`. Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createOne()` is not returning a promise that is connected to when both of its asynchronous operations are done so the caller of `createOne()` simply can't know when it's done.   Since `mainFunc()` calls `createOne()`, the caller of `mainFunc()` also can't know when everything is done.

I suggest you change it to this:

```
const createOne = async mainFunc((result) => {
  let table_id = result.data.internal_id;
  const response = await axios_Func({ graphQL query });
  return createTwo({ query: graphQL_query, table_id });
});
```

Or, if these really are independent operations and you'd like to run them in parallel, you could also do this:

```
const createOne = mainFunc((result) => {
  let table_id = result.data.internal_id;
  return Promise.all([
      axios_Func({ graphQL query }), 
      createTwo({ query: graphQL_query, table_id})
  ]);
});
```

Several points of advice:

1. Always return nested promises.  If you don't, that becomes an independent promise chain that the upper levels have no way to monitor, no way to know when it's done, no way to know if it had an error.
2. Use `async/await` when possible to avoid nesting and simplify the code.
3. All calling paths must have a handler for a rejected promise so there is no chance of an unhandled promise rejection.
4. `.then((res) => res)` is pointless.  It does nothing but add redundant code.  Remember that `.then()` always returns a promise.  So, `.then((res) => res)` returns a promise that resolves to `res`, but you already had a promise that resolves to `res` without that code.  So, it adds nothing useful.

Comment: How do I call `createThree` after `createTwo` finishes executing? I want to use the `async-await`

Comment: @Wyck - I fixed a couple typos.  FYI, you can just directly propose edits to fix things like that.

Comment: @jfriend00,  I am still stuck with how to accomplish merge these values into 1 array to look like [123, 456, 567, 897, 345, 987] outside of createTwo and then iterate over these after createOne and createTwo finish executing to call the createThree function?

Comment: @nb_nb_nb - Well the `createOne()` code you show doesn't do anything with either of the return values from `axios_Func()` or `createTwo()` so the code just seems incomplete and I don't know what else to suggest.  There's just not enough info here to know what returns what and what result you're trying to achieve.